# HANA Calculation View Filter

Tags: hana-studio

Ok so I feel like a numpty asking this, but ..
How do I apply a filter within a calculation view ?

My view has 1 source table, an Attribute View.
I have added the attrib view to a Projection.

Then I've been searching everywhere to apply a simple filter.
How can this be so hard to do work out ?
I must be missing something.

**UPDATE**
ok, so according to someone else (not in my company), I should be able to simply goto to projection node, right click on a column and 'Apply Filter'.

Unfortunately that option does not appear in my context menu when I right-click.

Any ideas why this might be ??

Answer (score 2):

The projection node immediately below Semantics will not give you Apply filter option in context menu. 
Please add one more Projection node and add your table in that and then try to Apply Filter from context menu option.

Answer (score 0):

You could click on the projection node
And on the Output pane to the right, scroll down to the **Filters > Expression** node.

Double-click on the Expression node to write a complex expression based on the columns of the projection node's context.